# function call in node.js code not possible

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, express, axios

how can I call the **getKeys()** function correctly in this node.js code. With **app.get(...)** the call works fine, with the function call **getKeys()** I get the error message ***"undefined"*** in console. Thanks for help.

Here my code:

```
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios')
const app = express()

app.get("/", async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get("https://m.myapp2go.de/services/APIgetblz")
        res.json(response.data)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})

async function getKeys() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('https://m.myapp2go.de/services/APIgetblz');
        const data = response.items;
        console.log(data);
        //res.send(data);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}

getKeys();

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "error" })
})

app.listen(3001)
```

error after await:

```
await getKeys();
^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Comment: Voting to close as "caused by a typo". You forgot a level of your data structure. `items` is a property on the data in the response. It isn't a property of the response itself. `const data = response.data.items;`

Comment: @Quentin good analysis. Thank you. That was the mistake. Works great now!

Answer (score 0):

`getKeys` is an `async` function that needs to be `await`ed

The latest version of Node.js, does [support top-level await](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v14.8.0/)

```js
await getKeys()
```

Alternatively you could wrap it in an IFFE

```js
async getKeys() { … }


(async () => {
  await getKeys();
})();
```

Comment: updated post above

Comment: I've added an alternative to my answer

Comment: would look very nice but delivers "undefined" again

Comment: Yeah, looks like an error in your code. Axios returns `data`: `const { data } = axios.post()`